I have a PoE wiring problem and need some help debugging
I have two Wi-Fi Access Points (APs) with direct connections from a PoE switch to the APs. These work correctly.
All RJ-45s plugged into the switch and I believe are wired according to 802.3af 568B (4&5 are DC+, 7&8 are DC-). Pins 1-8: 568B: G/W, G, O/W, Bl, Bl/W, O, Br/W, Br.
I have a 3rd AP that is wired from the PoE switch to a wall plate connector, and then I run a standard CAT5/6e cable to the AP. The AP doesn't get any power. If I add a PoE capable switch between the wall connector and AP, then the data lines work fine and the AP is powered.
I used an 8-line turn-around ethernet tester on the cable from the switch to the wall connector and all the pins show in order.
The wall plate connector uses something I have not seen before (but I don't run PoE cables very often). The wires are connected by color (not by pin). It is unclear if the wires and pins are straight-through or cross in some way, The pins and wires are enclosed in opaque plastic. I am guessing something in this connector is wrong.
When I moved into the house several of the the ethernet wall jacks did not work correctly. A neighbor helped fix them. He said the builder used a combination of Mode A and Mode B (or he might have said American and European wiring). For those he fixed, he changed them to be all the same.
Any thoughts on how to diagnose or fix?

Most likely, the loop resistance is too high. However, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and DIY are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [diy.se].

Solved! I double checked everything and I had the cable plugged into a non-POE port on the switch. I moved it to a PoE port and everything worked. Duh!
